# Android Studio Unable to start the daemon process. The project uses Gradle 3.3 which is incompatible with Java 11 or newer

Tags: android-studio

`

> Unable to start the daemon process.
>
> The project uses Gradle 3.3 which is incompatible with Java 11 or
> newer.
>
> Possible solution:
>
> - Upgrade Gradle wrapper to 4.8 version and re-import the project

`

I try to clone the android project, and the gradle is incompatible with my java, how to fix the problem to running the application?

Answer (score 0):

Delete  `.gradle`  file from the project directory, clean the cache and rebuild the project.

Make sure `plugin version` is the same as your `gradle version`

You can **SDK Manager** and install **APIs** needed.

That should work.